# Boostrap Vue JS table busy state loading indicator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Problem:  I want to display a busy loading icon when the table is still loading.

[image]
I'm using Boostrap-vue JS which is based on Boostrap and I'm using VueJS's "b-table" component, I will display around 3000 rows on this table.

The API request to get the data is very quick, around 3 seconds for the response but the table rendering is much longer than that.  I look up the documentation that shows me how to do set the table's busy state using [table busy state](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#table-busy-state) and [automated table busy state](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#automated-table-busy-state).

However, unless I misread the document, it treats busy state as in the time it takes for the actual request/response of the data itself.  In my case does not work because the table render of these data could take 30 seconds and I want to show the busy loading icon during this time.

Is there a proper way to do this and include the DOM render time into the busy time?

My attempt with the code so far,

```
    <b-table hover :items="activities.items" busy.sync="true" :fields="activities.fields">
         <template v-slot:table-busy>
               <div class="text-center text-danger my-2">
                     <b-spinner class="align-middle"></b-spinner>
                     <strong>Loading...</strong>
               </div>
         </template>
    </b-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not solve this problem in a such way (what you described is physically impossible because your page renders with 0 frames per second due it lag). You need to use libs which works with virtual DOM like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-virtual-table). In other way your table will be laggy and user unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data is quite large (3k rows in your case), you should try server-side pagination.

Here is some info for your reference: https://www.bezkoder.com/vue-pagination-axios/